# Choosing a template from a ViewArg in Revel

Tags: go, revel

Using the Revel framework, is it possible to chose a template based on the value of a ViewArg?

I defined a base controller which provides a method that renders content within *views/Layout.html*

```
type Controller struct {
    *revel.Controller
}

func(c *Controller) RenderView(view string, extraViewArgs ...interface{}) revel.Result {
    // ... omitted source
    c.ViewArgs["ContentTemplateName"] = view

    return c.RenderTemplate("layout.html")
}
```

An example controller implementing this is as follows

```
type MyController struct {
    Controller
}

func (c MyController) Index() revel.Result {
    bananas := "This is bananas"
    return c.RenderView("App/Bananas.html", bananas)
}
```

I then try to render "App/Bananas.html" within layout.html

```
{{set . "title" "Home"}}
{{template "header.html" .}}

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    {{template "flash.html" .}}
  </div>
  <!-- Left column of Content -->
  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
    {{template .ContentTemplateName .}}
  </div>
  <!-- //Left Column of Content -->

  <!-- Right column of summary -->
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 hidden-xs">
    <div class="container">
      {{template "sidebar.html" .}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- //Right column of summary -->
</div>

{{template "footer.html" .}}
```

This outputs the following result

```
ERROR 2018/08/31 17:46:10 template.go:338: Template compilation error (In layout.html around line 10):
unexpected ".ContentTe"... in template clause
ERROR 2018/08/31 17:46:10 server.go:99: Template Compilation Error (in layout.html:10): unexpected ".ContentTe"... in template clause
```

Comment: the `template` function does not allow to take a variable in input. It must be a static text template name. You can check for this behavior in the template package source code, the function responsible to parse the template name recognizes only `string` or `rawstring` https://golang.org/src/text/template/parse/parse.go#L582. Note also that the Template Node has a Field name that is a string, not a pipeline see https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/parse/#TemplateNode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a comment by @mh-cbon, it was discovered that **its not possible to use a variable as input to the `template` function**.

As a workaround to this problem to get closer to the desired features, I implemented the following (less than ideal) solution:

*base_content_view.html*

```
{{template "begin_content.html" . }}
  <!-- content here -->
{{template "end_content.html" . }}
```

*begin_content.html*

```
{{template "header.html" . }}

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    {{template "flash.html" .}}
  </div>
    <!-- Left column of Content -->
  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
```

*end_content.html*

```
  </div>
  <!-- //Left Column of Content -->

  <!-- Right column of summary -->
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 hidden-xs">
    <div class="container">
      {{template "sidebar.html" .}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- //Right column of summary -->

{{template "footer.html" .}}
```

base_content_view.html is a static file which is copy pasted as a template when making new views. This design does open other issues however serves as an example workaround for the limitation of the `template` function.